# Drilling down a obj to obtain data in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, dom

Essentially I am having a hard time getting the data from a data type into the DOM. What I want is the `src` values from the arrays to populate the `img` tags in the DOM

HTML:

```
<div id="container-fluid--secondary" class="container-fluid container-fluid--secondary">
   <section class="a">
      <div class="video-container">
         <img class="video-container__thumbnail" src="https://via.placeholder.com/250x141.png?text=Video Thumbnail 250px x 141px" alt="Video thumbnail">
         <img class="video-container__thumbnail" src="https://via.placeholder.com/250x141.png?text=Video Thumbnail 250px x 141px"
            alt="Video thumbnail">
         <img class="video-container__thumbnail" src="https://via.placeholder.com/250x141.png?text=Video Thumbnail 250px x 141px"
            alt="Video thumbnail">
      </div>
   </section>
   <section class="b">
      <div class="video-container">
         <img class="video-container__thumbnail" src="https://via.placeholder.com/250x141.png?text=Video Thumbnail 250px x 141px"
            alt="Video thumbnail">
         <img class="video-container__thumbnail" src="https://via.placeholder.com/250x141.png?text=Video Thumbnail 250px x 141px"
            alt="Video thumbnail">
         <img class="video-container__thumbnail" src="https://via.placeholder.com/250x141.png?text=Video Thumbnail 250px x 141px"
            alt="Video thumbnail">
      </div>
   </section>
</div>
```

JS:

```
var videos = {
    'a': [
        {
            'name': 'a',
            'src': 'https://foo/video/'
        },
        {
            'name': 'b',
            'src': 'https://bar/video/'
        },
        {
            'name': 'c',
            'src': 'https://baz/video/'
        }
    ],
    'b': [
        {
            'name': 'a',
            'src': 'https://fizz/video/'
        },
        {
            'name': 'b',
            'src': 'https://buzz/video/'
        },
        {
            'name': 'c',
            'src': 'https://blargh/video/'
        }
    ]
},

 containerFluidSecondary = document.getElementById('container-fluid--secondary'),
   videoNames = Object.keys(videos);     

        containerFluidSecondary.querySelectorAll('section')
        .forEach(function(section, i){
         if (section.className == videoNames[i]) {
            var videoContainer = Array.prototype.slice.call(section.getElementsByClassName('video-container')[0].children);

            videoContainer.forEach(function(img, i){
              for (var videoCategory in videos){
                console.log('videoCategory', videoCategory[i][i])
              }
            })
         }})
```

Comment: `videoCategory` has the value `"a"` or `"b"`. As such, `videoCategory[i][i]` makes no sense.

Comment: Yeah, I know I was just `console` ing things...

Comment: Please be careful with your [metasyntactic variables](http://www.catb.org/~esr/jargon/html/M/metasyntactic-variable.html). Substituting "fizz", "buzz" and such for such well-established names as "qux" and "corge" counters years of standardization work! ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`videoCategory` has the value `"a"` or `"b"`. As such, `videoCategory[i][i]` makes no sense.

Looks like you want:

```
containerFluidSecondary.querySelectorAll('section').forEach(function(section){
  section.querySelectorAll('img').forEach(function(img, i) {
    img.src = videos[section.className][i].src;
  });
});
```

```js
var videos = {
    'a': [
        {
            'name': 'a',
            'src': 'https://foo/video/'
        },
        {
            'name': 'b',
            'src': 'https://bar/video/'
        },
        {
            'name': 'c',
            'src': 'https://baz/video/'
        }
    ],
    'b': [
        {
            'name': 'a',
            'src': 'https://fizz/video/'
        },
        {
            'name': 'b',
            'src': 'https://buzz/video/'
        },
        {
            'name': 'c',
            'src': 'https://blargh/video/'
        }
    ]
};

document.querySelectorAll('section').forEach(function(section){
  section.querySelectorAll('img').forEach(function(img, i) {
    img.src = videos[section.className][i].src;
  });
});

document.querySelectorAll('section').forEach(function(section){
  section.querySelectorAll('img').forEach(function(img, i) {
    img.src = videos[section.className][i].src;
  });
});
```

```html
<div id="container-fluid--secondary" class="container-fluid container-fluid--secondary">
   <section class="a">
      <div class="video-container">
         <img class="video-container__thumbnail" src="https://via.placeholder.com/250x141.png?text=Video Thumbnail 250px x 141px" alt="Video thumbnail">
         <img class="video-container__thumbnail" src="https://via.placeholder.com/250x141.png?text=Video Thumbnail 250px x 141px"
            alt="Video thumbnail">
         <img class="video-container__thumbnail" src="https://via.placeholder.com/250x141.png?text=Video Thumbnail 250px x 141px"
            alt="Video thumbnail">
      </div>
   </section>
   <section class="b">
      <div class="video-container">
         <img class="video-container__thumbnail" src="https://via.placeholder.com/250x141.png?text=Video Thumbnail 250px x 141px"
            alt="Video thumbnail">
         <img class="video-container__thumbnail" src="https://via.placeholder.com/250x141.png?text=Video Thumbnail 250px x 141px"
            alt="Video thumbnail">
         <img class="video-container__thumbnail" src="https://via.placeholder.com/250x141.png?text=Video Thumbnail 250px x 141px"
            alt="Video thumbnail">
      </div>
   </section>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, like I said I was just `console.logging` stuff. Your solution didn't work,

I got `index.html:306 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined
 `

Comment: That could happen if `section` has more than just one class name and doesn't map directly to a property in `videos`. But it works for the example you provided. If a section has more than one class them then you have to adapt this a little.